# To read csv in google colaboratore

Tags: google-colaboratory

```py
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
import io

def ls(ruta = uploaded):
    return [arch.name for arch in io.StringIO((ruta)) if arch.is_file()]
divisas = ls()
```

I have this error:

TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not dict

Answer (score 2):

```html
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

Import the google.colab library for file upload then upload the file and pass file name inside the pandas read_csv function

```html
import io
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['heart.csv']))
df2.head()
```

[image]

Comment: correcto to here !! But I have one hundred files uploaded ... and I need including the names's file in a list previously before to make read_csv. In local, I do the following code for obtein it:

Comment: ```python         def ls(ruta = os.getcwd()):
    return [arch.name for arch in scandir(ruta) if arch.is_file()]
divisas = ls()```

Comment: def ls(ruta = uploaded):
    return [arch.name for arch in io.StringIO((ruta)) if arch.is_file()]
divisas = ls()

Answer (score 0):

I need to include the file names in divisas list